Images being uploaded via WP Media are not attached even they are used by some CPT posts
I would like to delete thousands of images on my WP websites which are no longer used by some CTP posts which have been removed even from Trash folder.
However, I found out that Images being uploaded via WP Media stay unattached even they are used by some CPT posts later. And some images being uploaded using WP Avatar are seen Unattached in WP Media Library too. Therefore I cannot delete those unattached images in WP Admin --> Library some of which will cause unfound links 404 on my website.
I have tried some famous plugins like Media Cleaner and others, but they appear to use the same behaviours from original WP Media library.
Is there a way of making those unattached images becoming attached when they are used by WP posts, and the same for avatar images?
Thanks

In theory you could probably hook into the Media Library to change the attachment of an image every time it is inserted into a different post. But that won't work retrospectively. You would have to loop through all postst and check all images whether they are attached to some existing post.
